# Ошибка подключения к Базе Данных на сервере! СОМ-Подключение!

Tags: 1с

Пытаюсь подключиться к серверной БД через COM соединение! Мой релиз платформы 8.3.9.2033. Версия платформы на сервере 8.3.5.1248.
Прочитал кучу информации в интернете, пытался регистрировать библиотеки(comcntr.dll), менял значения ключа в реестре, в ручную добавлял в "Службу компонентов" компоненты платформы, делал для них псевдонимы, но ничего не помогло. Само подключение к V83.COMConnector срабатывает, а потом когда я пытаюсь присоединиться к БД `БазаИсточник = COMСоединение.Connect(ПараметрыПодключения);`, возникает ошибка!
**Ошибка**:

> Произошла исключительная ситуация (V83.COMConnector.1): Несоответствие
>   версий клиента и сервера 1С:Предприятия Различаются версии клиента и
>   сервера (8.3.9.2033 - 8.3.5.1248), клиентское приложение:
>   COM-соединение

как была так и осталась!
Помогите с решением данного вопроса!

Comment: Зачем было всё это пробовать, если текст ошибки очень даже очевидно указывает на проблему?

Comment: Спасибо конечно, за очевидный ответ! Все горазды советовать платформы на сервере или на клиенте поменять, а если у тебя куча разных версий релизов на разных серверах! Что тогда...

Comment: Ну если так важно иметь разные версии ... То на клиенте надо установить версию аналогичную Серверу. ПРИ ЗАПУСКЕ 1С явно указывать версию совпадающую с Сервером !

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно убедиться что на сервере правильно установлена платформа.
   При установке - проставить галочку COM соединение
2. На клиенте установить ту же версию платформы